# The fields that are given to the settings appear in the subclasses when serializing the object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have classes like this.

```
public class Activity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Firm RelatedFirm { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Notes { get; set; }
}
public class Firm
{
   public Guid Id { get; set }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

After capturing the activity list, I'm sending them to a function to serialize. Within this function, serialize operation is performed according to certain parameters. One of these parameters is the fields in which I want the response to return. I want to return the Id, Name, RelatedFirm, Email and Notes fields for the activity and I want only the Id field to return to the Firm. The fields that I want to return to within the activity turn to me if they are in the firm.

This is my response;

```
{
  "Id": "9294bc10-d8e1-4590-9703-75b773110d1c",
  "Email": "q@q.com",
  "RelatedFirm": {
     "Id": "ebbe560b-f75d-4daf-9500-89a10487e51f",
     "Email": "x@x.com",
     "Notes": "87654323ıuyt43"
  },
  "Notes": null
}
```

This is also the answer I want to come;

```
{
   "Id": "9294bc10-d8e1-4590-9703-75b773110d1c",
   "Email": "q@q.com",
   "RelatedFirm": {
      "Id": "ebbe560b-f75d-4daf-9500-89a10487e51f"
    },
    "Notes": null
}
```

Is there any way I can stop this?

Comment: "The fields that are given to the settings appear in the subclasses when serializing the object" - the code doesn't show subclasses - can you clarify what you mean there? but it *sounds* like you're talking about "conditional serialization", which ... is a bit of an advanced topic. Frankly, I would suggest not trying to do that, but instead having **purpose specific types**, i.e. when you want to serialize something that looks like a `Firm` but only has an `Id`, you use a **type** that **only has an `Id`**

Comment: If anonymous type is an option then `Linq` is your friend you can use something like `var nObj = activityList.Select(s => new
            {
                s.Id,
                s.Email,
                s.Name,
                s.Notes,
                RelatedFirm = new { Id = s.RelatedFirm.Id }
            }).ToArray();` and create an anonymouse object in your serialization method.